# Show compactification of positive real plane is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R \Bbb P^2$

Tags: general-topology, projective-geometry, projective-space, compactification

$\Bbb R \Bbb P^2$ can be thought of as a compactification of $\Bbb R^2,$ and is formed by taking the quotient of $\Bbb R^{3}-\{0\}$ under the equivalence relation $x\sim \lambda x$ for all real numbers $\lambda\ne0.$

This is the same as identifying antipodal points on a sphere.

I think if we want an analogous compactification of the positive real plane $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0},$ then we have to take the quotient of $\Bbb R^3_{\gt 0}-\{(1,1)\}$ under the equivalence relation $x\sim x^{\lambda}$ for $\lambda\ne0.$

Well if $\Bbb R \Bbb P^2$ can be thought of as identifying antipodal points on a sphere then we need the right notion of a "sphere" in $\Bbb R^3_{\gt 0}.$ Then we could identify antipodal points of this object a get the right equivalence relation.

I'm going to work in a lower dimension:

$\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ will be considered in the following way $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2_{\gt0}$ where $f(x,y)=(e^x,e^y).$

And now define a circle in $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$: $Q^2:=\big\{(x,y) :\log^2(x)+\log^2(y)=1\big\}.$

And define lines $f_{\lambda}(x)=x^{\lambda}$ s.t. $\lambda$ is a real number. Then we can look at each line say $f_1(x)=x^1$ and see that this line intersects $Q^2$ at two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ which we will identify. Similarly identification process will happen for each $\lambda.$

Since I know two homeomorphic spaces $X$ and $Y$ admit homeomorphic one point compactifications, I think $\Bbb R \Bbb P^2$ is homeomorphic to the compactification of the positive real plane I outlined above.

> Is this compactification of $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R \Bbb P^2?$ What is the mapping?

Comment: "$x \sim \lambda x$" I can parse: $\lambda$ is a scalar and $x$ is a vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$.  "$x \sim x^\lambda$" I can't parse.  What is a scalar power of a vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @EricTowers That was my attempt at trying to construct the equivalence relation to achieve the compactification of the real positive plane. It might not be correct that's just what I got

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of $(1,2,3)^{-7}$, which is an $x^\lambda$.  What vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ is that?

Comment: The main question is about achieving the compactification of $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ and showing whether or not it's homeomorphic to the compactification of $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: That question is unanswerable if the equivalence relation is uninterpretable.

Comment: I have an idea I will edit it to make everything clear

Comment: What is $1$ in $\mathbb R^3?$ What do you mean by “a compactification?” Since the right half plane is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2,$ how is it not enough to indicate that $\mathbb RP^2$ is a compactification of $\mathbb R^2?$

Comment: The equivalence $x \sim \lambda x$ treats the entire linear subspace through the origin along $x$ as a single point -- all points on that line are a scalar multiple of the vector $x$.

Comment: @EricTowers okay yes I was trying to express that with $x^{\lambda}$ acting as my lines

Comment: And what does one-point compactification have to do with anything? The one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^2$ is $S^2$, not $\Bbb RP^2$.

Comment: The current prescription only identifies points of $Q^2$, which is homeomorphic to a circle.  It's interior disk is unmodified and its exterior annulus is unmodified.  In particular the open boundary along the positive $x$- and $y$-axes is a problem for compactness (as is the open boundary at infinity)

Comment: You say that $\Bbb{RP}^2$ can be though of as a compactification of $\Bbb{R}^2$.  Can you explain where the $\Bbb{R}^2$ is (in the construction you describe that starts with once punctured $\Bbb{R}^3$) that is made compact by the construction?  (I don't see the $\Bbb{R}^2$ in that construction, so I'm not clear what analogy you are using to try to do the same thing to the upper-right quarter-plane.)

Comment: In your "compactification of the positive real plane$\ \mathbb{R}_{>0}^2\ $", do you mean "$\ \mathbb{R}_{>0}^3-\{(1,1,1)\}\ $?" $\big($Since $\ (1,1)\not\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^3\ $, then $\ \mathbb{R}_{>0}^3-\{(1,1)\}\ $ is just $\ \mathbb{R}_{>0}^3\ $ itself.$\big)$

Comment: @Eric Towers If you take $\ \big\{\big\{\lambda x\,|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\big\}\,\big|\ x\in\mathbb{R}^3,x\ne0\,\big\}\ $ as your representation of $
\mathbb{RP}^2\ $, I'm guessing that the homeomorphic embedding $\ h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow$
$\mathbb{RP}^2\ $ which geocalc3 has in mind is given by $$
h(x,y)=\big\{\lambda(x,y,1)\,|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\big\}\ .
$$

Comment: If so, then $\ h\big(\mathbb{R}^2\big)=\mathbb{RP}^2\setminus\big\{\big\{\lambda (x,y,0)\,|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\big\}\,\big|\ (x,y)\ne(0,0)\,\big\}\ $—i.e. the projective plane minus the line at infinity.  Since $\ \mathbb{RP}^2\ $ is the closure of $\ h\big(\mathbb{R}^2\big)\ $ it could be considered as being a compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^2\ $, but it's not the one-point compactification.

Comment: Wikipedia says that: Real projective space RPn is a compactification of Euclidean space Rn. For each possible "direction" in which points in Rn can "escape", one new point at infinity is added (but each direction is identified with its opposite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are some nice, correct ideas lurking in your first four paragraphs, but they're not very clearly expressed because of ambiguities and possible errors in your notation.  However, I think you took a wrong turn when you chose to "work in a lower dimension".  When you do this,  what you'll end up with is a compactification not of $\ \mathbb{R}_{>0}^2\ $, but of $\ \mathbb{R}_{>0}\ $.  From some of your comments, I also suspect you're harbouring some misconceptions about projective spaces, and how they can be considered compactifications of Euclidean spaces.

Note first that $\ \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ $ is homeomorphic to $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $, with the generalisation $\ f_n:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ $ of the $\ f\ $ you give for $\ n=2\ $,
$$
f_n\big(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\big)=\big(e^{x_1},e^{x_2},\dots,e^{x_n}\big)\ ,
$$
providing a homeomorphism between them.  Since $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $ is a compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $, there is a homeomorphic embedding, $\ h_n:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{RP}^n\ $, of $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $ onto a dense subset $\ h_n\big(\mathbb{R}^n\big)\ $ of $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $. The composite, $\ h_nf_n^{-1}\ $, is then a homeomorphic embedding of  $\ \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ $  onto the same dense subset of $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $, thus showing that $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $ is a compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ $.

If you take $\ \big(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\big\{(0,0,\dots,0)\big\}\big)\big/\sim\ $ as your representation of $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $ (where $\ \sim\ $ is the equivalence relation defined by $\ x\sim\lambda x\ $ for any $\ \lambda\ne0\ $), then an *explicit* homeomorphism $\ h_n:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow$$\big(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\big\{(0,0,\dots,0)\big\}\big)\big/\sim\ $ is given by
\begin{align}
h_n\big(x_1,x_2,&\dots,x_n\big)=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\,\big|\,x\sim\big(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,1\big)\,\big\}\ ,
\end{align}
and so an explicit homeomorphism $\ h_nf_n^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\rightarrow$$\big(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\big\{(0,0,\dots,0)\big\}\big)\big/\sim\ $ is given by
\begin{align}
h_nf_n^{-1}\big(y_1,y_2,&\dots,y_n\big)=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\,\big|\,x\sim\big(\ln y_1,\ln y_2,\dots,\ln y_n,1\big)\,\big\}\ .
\end{align}
When using this representation, the complement, $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\setminus h_nf_n^{-1}\big(\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\big)\ $, of $\ h_nf_n^{-1}\big(\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\big)\ $ in $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $ is
$$
\big\{\big\{\lambda x\,\big|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\big\}\,\big|\,x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\big\{(0,0,\dots,0)\big\}, x_{n+1}=0\ \big\}\ ,
$$
which is homeomorphic to $\ \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}\ $. Thus, this embedding effectively makes $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $ into a disjoint union of  $\ \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ $ and $\ \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}\ $.  Since $\ \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}\ $ is not a singleton unless $\ n=1\ $, it is only for that value of $\ n\ $ that the embedding gives you a one-point compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ $.

In fact, $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $ *cannot* be a one-point compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ $ for $\ n\ne1\ $, because, as [Ted Shifrin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71348/ted-shifrin) points out for $\ n=2\ $ in one of the comments, the one-point compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $ $\big($or, equivalently, of $\ \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}\ \big)$ is (homeomorphic to) the $n$-sphere $\ S^n\  $, and $\ \mathbb{RP}^n\ $ is not homeomorphic to $\ S^n\ $ unless $\ n=1\ $.

As I understand it, you're trying to construct a compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^2_{>0}\ $ by mimicing in $\ \mathbb{R}^3_{>0}\setminus\big\{(1,1,1)\big\}\ $ the construction of $\ \mathbb{RP}^2\ $ as a copy of $\ S^2\ $ with its antipodal points identified.  You can certainly do this, simply by using the homeomorphism $\ f_3\ $ defined above to transfer the details of the construction from $\ \mathbb{R}^3\ $ to $\ \mathbb{R}^3_{>0}\ $, or, equivalently, from $\ \big(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\big\{(0,0,0)\big\}\big)\big/\sim\ $ to $\ \big(\mathbb{R}^3_{>0}\setminus\big\{(1,1,1)\big\}\big)\big/f_3(\sim)\ $.

If you do this, then "the right notion of a "sphere" in  $\ \mathbb{R}^3_{>0}\ $" turns out to be the surface $\ \mathbb{U}^2\ $ given by
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{U}^2=f_3\big(S^2\big)\\
=&\big\{\big(e^{y_1},e^{y_2},e^{y_3}\big)\,\big|\,y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2=1\,\big\}\\
=&\big\{\big(x_1,x_2,x_3\big)\in\mathbb{R}^3_{>0}\,\big|\,\big(\ln x_1\big)^2+\big(\ln x_2\big)^2+\big(\ln x_3\big)^2=1\,\big\}\ .
\end{align}
If $\ y,z\in\mathbb{R}^3_{>0}\setminus\big\{(1,1,1)\ $ then $\ f_3^{-1}\big(z_1,z_2,z_3\big)=$$\big(\ln z_1,\ln z_2,\ln z_3\big)\sim$$f_3^{-1}\big(y_1,y_2,y_3\big)=\big(\ln y_1,\ln y_2,\ln y_3\big)\ $ if and only if there is a real number $\ \lambda\ne0\ $ such that
$$
\big(\ln z_1,\ln z_2,\ln z_3\big)=\lambda\big(\ln y_1,\ln y_2,\ln y_3\big)\ ,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\big(z_1,z_2,z_3\big)=\big(y_1^\lambda,y_2^\lambda,y_3^\lambda\big)\ .
$$
Thus, under the homeomorphism $\ f_3\ $
, the "image" $\ f_3(\sim)\ $ of the equivalence relation $\ \sim\ $ on $\ \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\big\{(0,0,0)\big\}\ $ is the equivalence relation $\ \overline{\sim}\ $ defined on $\ \mathbb{R}^3_{>0}\setminus\big\{(1,1,1)\big\}\ $ by $\ \big(y_1,y_2,y_3\big)\overline{\sim}$$\big(y_1^\lambda,y_2^\lambda,y_3^\lambda\big)\ $ for all real  $\ \lambda\ne0\ $.

Two points $\ x,z\in\mathbb{U}^2\ $ will be "antipodal" to each other if $\ z\overline{\sim}x\ $—that is, $\ z_i=x_i^\lambda\ $ for some real number $\ \lambda\ne0\ $.  Since $\ z\in\mathbb{U}^2\ $, then
\begin{align}
1&=\big(\ln z_1\big)^2+\big(\ln z_2\big)^2+\big(\ln z_3\big)^2\\
&=\lambda^2\big(\big(\ln x_1\big)^2+\big(\ln x_2\big)^2+\big(\ln x_3\big)^2\big)\\
&=\lambda^2\ ,
\end{align}
because $\ x\in\mathbb{U}^2\ $. Thus $\ \lambda=\pm1\ $, and $\ z\ $ will only be different from $\ x\ $ if we take $\ \lambda=-1\ $. The point on $\ \mathbb{U}^2\ $ "antipodal" to $\ x\ $ is thus the point $\ \big(x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1},x_3^{-1}\big)\ $, which I will denote by $\ x^{-1}\ $.

Thus, the compactification you're looking for is
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{U}^2\big/\overline{\sim}\ =\big\{\big\{x,x^{-1}\big\}\,\big|\,x\in\mathbb{U}^2\,\big\}\\
=&\big\{\big\{x,x^{-1}\big\}\,\big|\,x\in\mathbb{R}^3_{>0}, \big(\ln x_1\big)^2+\big(\ln x_2\big)^2+\big(\ln x_3\big)^2=1\,\big\}\ .
\end{align}

A homeomorphism $\ \psi:\big(\mathbb{U}^2\big/\overline{\sim}\big)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\big\{(0,0,0)\big\}\big)\big/\sim\ $ between this representation of $\ \mathbb{RP}^2\ $ and the more standard representation $\ \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\big\{(0,0,0)\big\}\big)\big/\sim\ $ is easy enough to obtain from a modification of $\ f_3^{-1}\ $:
$$
\psi(y)=\big\{\,\lambda \big(\ln x_1,\ln x_2, \ln x_3\big)\,\big|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, x\in y\,\big\}\ .
$$

What isn't quite so obvious is how to see directly that $\ \mathbb{U}^2\big/\overline{\sim}\ $ can be regarded as a compactification of $\ \mathbb{R}^2_{>0}\ $ by exhibiting an explicit homeomorphism of the latter onto a dense subset of the former.  But we can do this by simply composing the mapping $\ h_2f_2^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^2_{>0}\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\big\{(0,0,0)\big\}\big)\big/\sim\ $ with the inverse of $\ \psi\ $, although the resulting expression is somewhat complicated:
\begin{align}
&\psi^{-1}h_2f_2^{-1}\big(y_1,y_2\big)\\
&=\left\{\left(y_1^{-d\left(y_1,y_2\right)},y_2^{-d\left(y_1,y_2\right)},e^{-d\left(y_1,y_2\right)}\right), \left(y_1^{d\left(y_1,y_2\right)},y_2^{d\left(y_1,y_2\right)},e^{d\left(y_1,y_2\right)}\right)\right\}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ d\big(y_1,y_2\big)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\ln y_1)^2+(\ln y_2)^2 +1}}\ $.

The image $\ \psi^{-1}h_2f_2^{-1}\big(\mathbb{R}^2_{>0}\big)\ $ of $\ \mathbb{R}^2_{>0}\ $ under this mapping is
$$
\psi^{-1}h_2f_2^{-1}\big(\mathbb{R}^2_{>0}\big)=\big\{\big\{x,x^{-1}\big\}\,\big|\,x\in\mathbb{U}^2, x_3\ne1\,\big\}\ ,
$$
whose complement
$$
\big\{\big\{x,x^{-1}\big\}\,\big|\,x\in\mathbb{U}^2, x_3=1\,\big\}
$$
in $\ \mathbb{U}^2\big/\overline{\sim}\ $ is homeomorphic to $\ \mathbb{RP}^1\ $, and hence to a circle.